# Getting consistent color of lines, start and end markers

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a set of lines that all have end markers (one of four types).  They have one of two types of start  marker (either circle or nothing).   I want each line along with its start and end marker to have the same color.

I have defined my colors as a `var` within the `d3.csv` function.    It seems to me that the issue is with the `id` of my start markers within the second `defs`.  I have generated id's for all marker types rather than just the circle/none options.  I think that I might need 8 different ids here (one for either circle/none along with four different colors representing the four end marker possibilities).   At the moment all start markers are just showing up with the color assigned to the generic circle start marker.

[Here is a bl.ocks example](http://bl.ocks.org/jalapic/1de2ce91509512163a00)  - this also contains the csv file with some data.

Here is the script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


var svg = d3.select("body") 
      .append("svg")           
      .attr("width", 600)      
      .attr("height", 600);   


d3.csv("data/myarrows.csv", dottype1, function(error, lines) {


  var data = [
    { id: 0, name: 'circle', path: 'M 0, 0  m -5, 0  a 5,5 0 1,0 10,0  a 5,5 0 1,0 -10,0', viewbox: '-6 -6 12 12'}
  , { id: 1, name: 'square', path: 'M 0,0 m -5,-5 L 5,-5 L 5,5 L -5,5 Z', viewbox: '-5 -5 10 10' }
  , { id: 2, name: 'arrow', path: 'M 0,0 m -5,-5 L 5,0 L -5,5 Z', viewbox: '-5 -5 10 10' }
  , { id: 3, name: 'stub', path: 'M 0,0 m -1,-5 L 1,-5 L 1,5 L -1,5 Z', viewbox: '-1 -5 2 10' }
  , { id: 4, name: 'none', path: '', viewbox: '' }
    ]

var color = d3.scale.category10();

svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(lines)
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.x1; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.y1; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.x2; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.y2; })
      .attr("marker-start", function(d) { return 'url(#startmarker_' + d.startname  + ')' })
      .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return 'url(#marker_' + d.name  + ')' })
   //   .style("stroke", "brown")           
      .style("stroke", function(d) {return d.color = color(d.name); })           
   // .attr('stroke', function(d,i) { return color(i)})
      .style("stroke-width", 3)          
      .style("stroke-linecap", "square") 
               ;

svg.append("svg:defs")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("svg:marker") 
      .attr('id', function(d){ return 'marker_' + d.name})
      .attr('viewBox', function(d){ return d.viewbox })
      .attr('refX', 0)
      .attr('markerWidth', 4)
      .attr('markerHeight', 4)
   //   .style("stroke", "brown") 
     .style("stroke", function(d) {return d.color = color(d.name); })  
     //  .style("fill", "brown")        
       .style("fill", function(d) {return d.color = color(d.name); })  
       .attr('orient', 'auto')
      .append('svg:path')
      .attr('d', function(d){ return d.path })
                 ;

svg.append("svg:defs")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("svg:marker") 
      .attr('id', function(d){ return 'startmarker_' + d.name})
      .attr('viewBox', function(d){ return d.viewbox })
      .attr('refX', 6)
      .attr('markerWidth', 3)
      .attr('markerHeight', 3)
 //   .style("stroke", "brown") 
      .style("stroke-width", 2)          
      .style("stroke", function(d) {return d.color = color(d.name); })  
       .style("fill", "none")          
      .attr('orient', 'auto')
      .append('svg:path')
      .attr('d', function(d){ return d.path })
                 ;
});




function dottype1(d) {
  d.x1 = +d.x1x1;
  d.y1 = +d.y1y1;
  d.x2 = +d.x2x2;
  d.y2 = +d.y2y2;
  d.startname = d.starttype;
  d.name = d.endtype;
   return d;
}



  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a hacky solution, but it is not optimal.  In this example, I simply removed the start-markers and added circles.  I had to add another variable to the csv to vary the opacity of the circle (0 or 1) based on presence/absence of the circle.    The issue here is that the circles don't sit nicely next to the end of the line. Even using `.style("stroke-linecap", "butt")` the line still overlaps the edge of the circle.

So, I'm still looking for a solution using start-markers, but this is ok-ish.

[bl.ocks.org example](http://bl.ocks.org/jalapic/ef51a2623e26898db1df)